# What is this red statue?

Tags: terraria

I found this statue. It appeared out of nowhere, and cannot be mined(pickaxe and sword both just go over it.) It also goes in front of the player, unlike anything ive seen.

[image: One screenshot of the item]

[image: Another screenshot of the item]

Answer (score 31):

That's an [Orange Bloodroot](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Orange_Bloodroot), a material used to craft Orange Dye. If your inventory wasn't full, you would be able to pick it up.